# Android Will not display circle where a variable is one of the parameters

Tags: java, android, canvas, geometry

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView drawingImageView;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    float t;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Display display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        float width = size.x;
        float height = size.y;

        drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // Path

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            canvas.drawPath(DrawCircle(1f, (t*0.05f), 100), paint); //<------Does not work
            canvas.drawPath(DrawCircle(1f, 0.1f, 100), paint); //<----- works
            t++;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    public Path DrawCircle(float PercOfScreen, float Amount, int vertexCount){
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        float width = size.x;
        float height = size.y;

        Path p = new Path();

        int center_x = (int) width/2;
        int center_y = (int) height/2;

        int bound;

        if (height > width){
            bound = (int) width;
        }
        else{
            bound = (int) height;
        }

        int radius = (int) (PercOfScreen*bound/2);
        float Pi = (float) Math.PI;

        p.moveTo(center_x, center_y);

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount*Amount; ++i){
            float percent = (i / (float) (vertexCount-1));
            double rad = percent * 2f*Pi;

            //vertex position
            float outer_x = center_x + radius * (float)Math.cos(rad);
            float outer_y = center_y + radius * (float)Math.sin(rad);
            p.lineTo(outer_x, outer_y);
        }

        return p;
    }
}
```

The above code will not display part of a circle if there is a variable in the parameters, but will if there is no variable. Why is this?

Also, for anyone who wants one, simple function to display a circle or part of a circle.

Comment: Where did you instantiate the variable `t`?

Comment: Thank you i don't know how I missed that